# Unable to run h1.cmd() on mininet custom topology

Tags: python, mininet

I am new to Mininet and I am creating a custom topology. I have two concerns regarding my code, which I hope someone can help with.

1. I want to be able to set arp entries in the mininet script so that when I initialize the network, the nodes would already have the ARP tables. I believe I can do this with the h1.cmd() command for host h1, but I am getting the error when I run the code.

The error is

Caught exception. Cleaning up...
KeyError: 'h1'

Can someone advise what is wrong with the code?

2. I want to be able to set bandwidth and delay between the switches in my topology. I believe the code already does that, but how do we test this when the network is initialized? Is there another way besides iperf?

My code is as below:

```
    from mininet.topo import Topo
    from mininet.cli import CLI
    from mininet.net import Mininet
    from mininet.link import TCLink

    class MyTopo( Topo ):
        def __init__( self ):
            "Create custom topo"
            Topo.__init__( self ) #Initialize topology

            #Add hosts and switches
            h1 = self.addHost( 'h1', ip='10.0.0.1/24' )
            h2 = self.addHost( 'h2', ip='10.0.0.2/24' )
            h3 = self.addHost( 'h3', ip='10.0.0.3/24' )
            h4 = self.addHost( 'h4', ip='10.0.0.4/24' )
            server1 = self.addHost( 'server1', ip='10.0.0.5/24' )
            server2 = self.addHost( 'server2', ip='10.0.0.6/24' )
            s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1')
            s2 = self.addSwitch( 's2')
            s3 = self.addSwitch( 's3')
            s4 = self.addSwitch( 's4')

            # Add links
            self.addLink( h1, s1,1,1 )
            self.addLink( h2, s1,1,2 )
            self.addLink( h3, s2,1,1 )
            self.addLink( h4, s2,1,2 )
            self.addLink( s1, s2,3,3,cls=TCLink,bw=200,delay='10ms' )
            self.addLink( s1, s3,4,4,cls=TCLink,bw=500,delay='10ms' )
            self.addLink( s2, s4,4,4,cls=TCLink,bw=500,delay='10ms' )
            self.addLink( s3, s4,3,3,cls=TCLink,bw=500,delay='10ms' )
            self.addLink( s3, server1,1,1,cls=TCLink,bw=1000 )
            self.addLink( s4, server2,1,1,cls=TClink,bw=1000 )
            self.addLink( s3, server2,2,2,cls=TCLink,bw=1000 )
            self.addLink( s4, server1,2,2,cls=TCLink,bw=1000 )


    net = Mininet( topo=Topo() )
    net.start()
    h1 = net.get('h1')
    h1.cmd('arp -s 10.0.0.2 00:00:00:00:00:02')
    CLI(net)
    net.stop()

    topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

The error I get is:

"Caught exception. Cleaning up..."

"KeyError: 'h1'"

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a few minutes to get familiar with the site and its rules. In particular, do not post screenshots when you have plain text available. You can use three backticks above and below your code to format it properly in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited it now!

Answer (score 0):

You create a topology MyTopo but you never use it.

the line `net = Mininet( topo=Topo() )` uses topology defined in class Topo, not the topology that you created in MyTopo().

You really ought to tidy this up, but I believe that if you changed the aforementioned line to `net = Mininet( topo=MyTopo() )` you will get the behaviour you expect. In future, please do not paste plaintext of your issue, but provide a stacktrace or a screenshot.